# How to copy rows to another sheet by using criteria in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've problem to copy some info created in excel 2010, from one sheet to another, and I would like to set criteria to filter records while copy.

For example, Sheet called `January` has some work registered in different rows, and I have a column set up for work situation (`Done`, `Payed`, `In Progress`).

I'd like to set up an automatic copy for all the works, in Sheet `February`, if row meets the criteria.

Following are the criteria:

- Time limit is end of each month, I've  current date in "F1" used `=TODAY()`.
- Criteria in column "U", is `in progress`.

Comment: Why don't you use Advance Filter is easier and faster way to Filter records. What  you have to do the the OUTPUT range in Sheet February, Excel will filter records from Sheet January & Copy as output in Sheet February !

Comment: What automatic copy exactly means for you? You might use formulas / pivot table / macro; those all have different pros and cons, we would need to know your situation better to be able to suggest the best option.

Comment: Hy! I dont know why the text from my original message was changed, i put much more info in it. Automatic copy is needed to exclude human errors (secretary)  :)  i have no experience in excel but  i managed to create a very good database in it by looking on the web, but this one owerrun my knowledge...

Comment: so one more time:)  Sheet Jan. has some works starting whit A5 going down 100, 150 depends from month, ad going to U5(A5-U5 different data about the work), but if the work is not finished, it goes to the next month, that why id like to move the entiere row in the next sheet (ex.February).

Comment: i created 12 sheets for each month and put the same formating, formulas ect.....  the works are registred from A5 down and in collum U i have the status of the works "finished", "payed", "in progress". the question was, can be set to copy some rows in the next sheet based on the status of the work, in this case "in progress" and this to be made automatic if the month ends, like 31.01.2018 00:00. hope this is beter then the original request. thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

*Write this Array formula in **Cell A2 of Sheet February** & confirm it by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, then fill Right & Down.*

*Excel will add curly braces around it to indicate that it is an array formula like shown below:*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(January!$A$2:$C$25, SMALL(IF((INDEX(January!$A$2:$C$25, , January!$E$2)=January!$E$3)*(INDEX(January!$A$2:$C$25, , January!$F$2)=January!$F$3), MATCH(ROW(January!$A$2:$C$25), ROW(January!$A$2:$C$25)), ""), ROWS(A2:$A$2)), COLUMNS($A$2:A2)),"")}
```

**Note:** *Following are the Criteria.*

1. `January!$E$2` has Column Number of `Date Column` and `January!$E$3` has value `08/31/2018` (Last date of Month).
2. `January!$F$2` has Column Number of `Work Situation` and `January!$F$3` has value `In Progress`.

*Adjust cell references & Sheet Name in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: thank you Rajesh S, i wil try.... hope it works.... only that i have some info in A2, but i wil try to replace the formula...

Comment: @Csaba,,it's properly working I've tested it !