# Excel 2016: formula to get data from a different spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I need help with this tricky formula: `='[DATA.xlsm]2018'!$G$6` It works but...

Spreadsheet with formula:

[image: Spreadsheet with formula]

Spreadsheet with data:

[image: Spreadsheet with data]

I need the formula to determine where to find the data. 
See  image. The formula in in the VALUE column B. The QTR info in column A tells me where to look for the data in the `<data>` image.

The four QTR matching fields are D1, I1, N1, S1. Then the OFFSET is 3 columns (for example: D1=1Q18 and col G is the data column, col L for 2Q18, etc) and the OFFSET row is 5 (meaning row 6). Hopefully OFFSET(5,3) is correct.

On row 10 I need the formula in B10 to read 1Q18 in A10 and (know) to go to '[DATA.xlsx]2018' and find that "1Q18" is D1 and then use the OFFSET(5,3) to find the value "1.80".

When we get down to row 14 on the FORMULA sheet it'll see "1Q19" in A14 and {know} to go to '[DATA.xlsx]2019'.  Each year has a new tab sheet named by the 4-digit year.

Comment: It is hard to follow what you want. I have the feeling you may need to use `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Refer this https://superuser.com/questions/1351540. It copies/reads data from one to other. What you need to do is, add  Wbook name with Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, you do need [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66).  But you also need to [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) the quarter you are looking up.  I've split the formula into 2 cells so you can see it piece-by-piece, but once you understand it you can easily combine the two.

I doctored up a fake set of data (I used a worksheet named "Data" in the same workbook):
[image: Excel data].

Then I called the other sheet "Report".  In the report sheet you first want to `MATCH` the quarter you are looking up to a position in your data sheet.  `MATCH` has the definition:

> MATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array, [match_type])

So we set the `lookup_value` to the quarter you are after, the `lookup_array` to the data set, and the `match_type` to 0 (exact match).  Note this only works on a single *array* (row or col), you can't provide a 2D grid of cells.  This will give us a relative position in the array, 1 indexed (first item returns 1, not 0).

We then use this information with `OFFSET`.  The definition for offset is this:

> OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

In this case reference is a single cell.  You don't need to provide an array or grid of cells.  So in my case I pass `Data!$B$1`.  For `rows` we need to offset 2 rows down.  The amount of columns across is trickier.  Since the `MATCH` function gave as a reference position that starts at 1, we are already moving to the second month.  So for `cols` we need the results of `MATCH` *plus 2*.

So finally we get a report sheet that looks something like this:
[image: Excel report]

Comment: The note in this comment box says not to say thanks here. Please tell me where/how I can express my appreciation for all to see AND how to I make it known that this answer solved the problem with a great, detailed explanation of how you did it?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @GregM.  The help section details what to do when [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.